# $.getJSON only returns partial and an empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube-api

I am creating an object to handle the YouTube API and I have two methods:

- `getCommentList` - getting a url for the current upload,for example `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments?alt=json` and return an array of objects - author of the comment and the content of the comment.
- `getEntriesObject` - returning an array with objects for each upload entry we have title,thumbnail,and the comment list that returned from `getCommentList`

My jQuery code:

```
var Youtube = {

   getCommentObject : function(url){
      if( url ){
         var currentCommentFeed = {},
             commentsList = [];

         $.getJSON(url,function(data){
            $.each(data.feed.entry,function(index){
               currentCommentFeed = this;

               commentsList.push({
                  author : currentCommentFeed.author[0].name.$t,
                  content : currentCommentFeed.content.$t
               });

            });

            return commentsList;
         });

      }
   },

   getEntriesObject : function(){
      var username = 'SOMEYOUTUBEUSERHERE',
          url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' + username + '/uploads?alt=json',
          currentEntry = {},
          currentObject = {},
          entryList = [];

      // Scope fix
      var that = this;

      $.getJSON(url,function(data){
         $.each(data.feed.entry, function(index){

            // Caching our entry
            currentEntry = this;

            // Adding our entry title and thumbnail
            currentObject = {
               title: currentEntry.title.$t
            };

            if(currentEntry.media$group.media$thumbnail.length == 4)
               currentObject['thumbnail'] = currentEntry.media$group.media$thumbnail[3].url;

            // Let`s get the comments - undefined....
            currentObject['comments'] = that.getCommentObject(currentEntry.gd$comments.gd$feedLink.href + "?alt=json");

            console.log(currentObject);
            entryList.push(currentObject);
         });
      });

      return entryList;

   }

   /*

   entry[i].title.$t
   entry[i].gd$comments.gd$feedLink.href + "?alt=json"
   entry[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[3]

   // Comments 
   entry[i].author.name.$t
   entry[i].author.content.$t
   */
};
```

I have `console.log(currentObject)` and am getting the title. But am not getting the thumbnail URL and the comments.

In addition, when I run `getEntriesObject` I get back an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call return in the callback to `$.getJSON` you are returning only that callback function, not the "outer" `getCommentObject`. Thus when you later call `that.getCommentObject` you're not getting anything in return (`undefined`).

```
getCommentObject: function(url){
   if( url ){

      // Snip ...

      $.getJSON(url,function(data){

         // Snip ...

         return commentsList; // <- Here
      });

   }
}
```

To amend this make `getCommentObject` take a callback function.

```
getCommentObject: function(url, callback){
   if( url ){

      // Snip ...

      $.getJSON(url,function(data){

         // Snip

         // Remove the return statement
         callback(commentsList);
      });

   }
}
```

Call this function like this:

```
that.getCommentObject(
    currentEntry.gd$comments.gd$feedLink.href + "?alt=json", 
    function (commentsList) { 
       currentObject['comments'] = commentsList; 
});
```

Replacing

```
currentObject['comments'] = that.getCommentObject(currentEntry.gd$comments.gd$feedLink.href + "?alt=json");
```

Comment: @Yosy: If an answer is correct please use the green checkmark to indicate it!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the empty comments because the return statement is in the wrong place. It is in the getJSON callback function. You need to move it from line no 19 to 21 so that it becomes the return statement for getCommentObject. This will fix the first problem. (comments undefined)

Second getEntriesObject is empty because, for some users youtube is returning "Service Unavailable" error for the json request. This happened for when I tried with some random username on youtube.

I checked your program with youtube username "google". After changing the return statement it worked fine.

Hope this helps.